# RichTextBox как DataTemplate в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, виртуализация

Доброго времени суток! У меня в качестве ListView.ItemTemplate является RichTextBox с забинденным Document'ом. В ListView включена виртуализация, но, прокручивая данный элемент, потребление памяти увеличивается и увеличивается. Пробовал забиндить то же самое на TextBlock и с памятью все было ок. Но, к сожалению, TextBlock не подходит, т.к. не поддерживает выделение. И TextBox тоже не подходит, т.к. вместе с текстом необходимо выводить изображения. Помогите пожалуйста

VIEW:

```
<Style x:Key="richBox" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsDocumentEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#11294f" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
    <richBox:BindableRichTextBox Margin="0"
                             AutoWordSelection="True"
                             UndoLimit="0"
                             Document="{Binding message,
                                                Converter={StaticResource documentConverter},
                                                Mode=OneWay}"
                             Padding="0"
                             Style="{StaticResource richBox}">
    <richBox:BindableRichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </richBox:BindableRichTextBox.Resources>
</richBox:BindableRichTextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="lvItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        Margin="5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit" Value="Pixel" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource lvItemStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
</Style>

<ListView Grid.Row="0"
          Focusable="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemListViewSource},
                                NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
          KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}"
          Style="{StaticResource lvStyle}" />
```

BindableRichTextBox:

```
public class BindableRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public BindableRichTextBox()
    {
         var commandBindings = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy);
        commandBindings.Executed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
            if (rtb == null)
            {
                args.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
            Clipboard.SetText(rtb.Selection.TextSelectionToString());
            args.Handled = true;
        };

        this.CommandBindings.Add(commandBindings);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Document", typeof(FlowDocument),
        typeof(BindableRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDocumentChanged)));

    public new FlowDocument Document
    {
        get
        {
            return (FlowDocument)this.GetValue(DocumentProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(DocumentProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var rtb = (RichTextBox)obj;
            rtb.Document = (FlowDocument)args.NewValue ?? new FlowDocument();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class DocumentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Regex RE_URL = new Regex(@"(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?");

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = new FlowDocument();

            var s = value as string;
            if (s != null)
            {

                var paragraph = new Paragraph();

                var last_pos = 0;
                foreach (Match match in RE_URL.Matches(s))
                {
                    if (match.Index != last_pos)
                    {
                        var raw_text = s.Substring(last_pos, match.Index - last_pos);
                        paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(EmojiHelper.DisplayEmoji(raw_text));
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        var link = new Hyperlink(new Run(match.Value))
                        {
                            NavigateUri = new Uri(match.Value)
                        };
                        link.Click += OnUrlClick;

                        paragraph.Inlines.Add(link);
                    }
                    catch { }

                    last_pos = match.Index + match.Length;
                }

                if (last_pos < s.Length)
                    paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(EmojiHelper.DisplayEmoji(s.Substring(last_pos)));

                doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
            }

            return doc;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    private static void OnUrlClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var link = (Hyperlink)sender;
            Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.ToString());
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

UPDATED VIEW:

```
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemListViewSource"
                              IsLiveSortingRequested="True"
                              Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                                               Path=Tag.Messages}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="date" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    <Style x:Key="lvItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


<Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit" Value="Pixel" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource lvItemStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>   


 <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="0,7,0,7">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="5,0,10,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource getAvatarForChat},
                                        Path=fromId,
                                        Mode=OneWay,
                                        ConverterParameter=40}">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <EllipseGeometry Center="20,20"
                                         RadiusX="20"
                                         RadiusY="20" />
                    </Image.Clip>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="13"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                           Padding="0"
                           Text="{Binding chatTitle, Mode=OneWay" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="13"
                           FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                           Padding="0"
                           Text="{Binding Path=date,
                                          Converter={StaticResource dateConverter},
                                          ConverterParameter=HH:mm,
                                          Mode=OneWay}" />

        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="0,3,0,0"
                                    Document="{Binding message,
                                               Converter={StaticResource documentConverter},
                                               Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Padding="0"/>

            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


     <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemListViewSource},
                                        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}""
          ItemTemplate="StaticResource MessageTemplate"
                  Style="{StaticResource lvStyle}">
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть код, а еще лучше [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Отлично...Не могу взять в толк, у вас что `RichTextBox` только для чтения используется?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, всё верно, мне необходим элемент, которой поддерживал бы выделение, вывод текста, и изображений, и гиперлинков, другого я найти не смог

Comment: Тогда намного проще использовать обычный `FlowDocument`

Comment: К сожалению, это проблему полностью не решило, но потребление памяти немного уменьшилось, спасибо

Comment: Если покажите обновленный код, то возможно смогу что-то подсказать

Comment: Удалось найти ответ на вопрос?

Comment: К сожалению, пока еще не нашел ответа

Comment: Тогда может покажите обновленный код?

Comment: Попробуйте применить memory profiler и посмотреть, кто держит объекты в памяти.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать конвертер, т.е. один раз просто _мапните_ ваши данные и привязывайтесь сразу к `FlowDocument`.

Comment: @VladD, смотрел с помощью JetBrains dotMemory, всё в unmanaged memory. Может ли memory profiler как-то более подробнее показать ситуацию?

Comment: @AntonMan'kov: Ну, это, возможно, картинки. Попробуйте посмотреть, у каких управляемых (managed) объектов есть ссылки на эту неуправляемую память. Ну или хотя бы какие управляемые объекты остаются в памяти после прокручивания.